# regular expression to get folder name from URL

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

Is it possible to get folder name from a URL?

For example,

```
https://inside.nov.com/wh/pc/testSourceLib/Folder Z/SubFolder Z1/Copy files from one Document Library to another using Nintex Workflow _ My Learnings.pdf
```

where

- `https://inside.nov.com/wh/pc/` is the Web URL
- `testSourceLib` is the library name
- `Folder Z/Subfolder z1` is the folder name

I need to extract `/Folder Z/Subfolder z1` from the above URL.

I tried `([^\/]*)$` and it gives me the file name `Copy files from one Document Library to another using Nintex Workflow _ My Learnings.pdf`.

Comment: Try `[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)` with the Extract option.

Comment: Is there some reason you must use a Regex for this and not use the built-in [`Uri.GetComponents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods which already do this?

Comment: Yes. I am using Nintex workflow and It only takes .net friendly regex and I can't have any c# codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead based regex with the *Extract* option:

```
/[^/]+/[^/]+(?=/[^/]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d*%24%29&i=https%3a%2f%2finside.nov.com%2fwh%2fpc%2ftestSourceLib%2fFolder+Z%2fSubFolder+Z1%2fCopy+files+from+one+Document+Library+to+another+using+Nintex+Workflow+_+My+Learnings.pdf)

[image]

*Pattern details*:

- `[^/]+` - 1 or more characters other than `/`...
- `(?=/[^/]*$)`  - followed with `/`, zero or more characters other than `/` (`[^/]*`) and then the end of string (`$`). The construct is a positive lookahead that is a zero-width assertion that does not consume the text (not putting it into the returned match) that requires some text to the right of the current location in the string.

To shorten the pattern a bit, you may wrap the `/[^/]+` subpattern with a non-capturing group and apply a limiting quantifier on it:

```
(?:/[^/]+){2}(?=/[^/]*$)
```

See  [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%29%7B2%7D%28%3F%3D%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D*%24%29&i=https%3A%2F%2Finside.nov.com%2Fwh%2Fpc%2FtestSourceLib%2FFolder%20Z%2FSubFolder%20Z1%2FCopy%20files%20from%20one%20Document%20Library%20to%20another%20using%20Nintex%20Workflow%20_%20My%20Learnings.pdf)

Comment: This gives me "SubFolder Z1" but I need "/Folder Z/SubFolder Z1/" to be the output

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.  You saved my day. Thanks Thanks Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that in the string regex patterns where regex delimiters are not used, the `/` does not have to be escaped as it is not a regex special metacharacter.

Comment: Wictor, I have a question sometimes I only have 1 folder or 3 sub folders the expression works if I have 2 folders. What happens if I have more than 3 or 4 subfolders.

Comment: That depends on what is static (=constant) in the pattern. If the starting substring is the same, use `(?<=https://inside.nov.com/wh/pc/testSourceLib)(?:/[^/]+)+(?=/[^/]*$)`

Comment: Yes, the stating url is static. For example below https://inside.nov.com/wh/pc/testSourceLib/Full Scope/VOPAK VI  - 4902/Supporting Documents/Contract Value Change/Final Settlement Agreement/Vo Punch List Mechanical_ Civil — E — I.pdf I have 5 folders.

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dhttps%3a%2f%2finside.nov.com%2fwh%2fpc%2ftestSourceLib%29%28%3f%3a%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b%29%2b%28%3f%3d%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d*%24%29&i=https%3a%2f%2finside.nov.com%2fwh%2fpc%2ftestSourceLib%2fFull+Scope%2fVOPAK+VI+-+4902%2fSupporting+Documents%2fContract+Value+Change%2fFinal+Settlement+Agreement%2fVo+Punch+List+Mechanical_+Civil+%e2%80%94+E+%e2%80%94+I.pdf).

Comment: I truly appreciate it your help and willing to teach me the details. You ROCK...... THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR TIME AND WILLING TO HELP SO QUICKLY.